# How to stream data from mongodb in Structured Streaming?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Is it possible to use spark structured streaming to read data from mongo db with a readStream ?

For standard use of structured streaming, I usually do so:

```
val dataFrame = spark.readStream.format("parquet").option("header","true").schema(customSchema).load(path)
      val query = preprocessedData.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()
      query.awaitTermination()
```

And i know how to read data from mongo with spark :

```
val sparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder
      .master("local")
      .appName("MongoSparkConnector")
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", mongodb_input_uri)
      .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", mongodb_output_uri)
      .getOrCreate()

val data = sparkSession.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()
```

But now I want to use these two concepts to set up a structured streaming on a mongodb source, (to read only, I do not need to write in mongo)

Comment: Did you try `sparkSession.readStream.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")`?

Comment: yep, doesn't exist ...

Comment: Did it work with `sparkSession.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")`? It didn't, did it?

Comment: No it didn't work, i don't think it's already available

Comment: Did you start `spark-shell` with `--packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.1` as described in https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala-api/?

Comment: did you manage to readStream from mongoDB with spark structured streaming, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @scalacode no, But i find an other way to stream mongodb without spark, by tailing the oplog of mongodb.